# how to prevent Fragments firing onCreate&onCreateView on activity recreation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

So I have activities A, B, C
App flow is A->B->C

A,B are connected with logging-in functionality and are launched only once to log in.
Whole app is inside C Activity. A,B are alive when user uses C. Everything works fine.

Now..

I kill the PID of the app. then select it from task manager.

A is not up, B is not up, C->onCreate(not null) fires.

I can detect this situation by checking if there are instances of A or B alive. 
So now that I am aware that this particular scenario has happened I want to restart the app -> to activity A, so its a fresh launch.

The problem is restarting the app inside onCraete(not null)

in onCreate(not null) in activity C I do something like this :

```
if (A==null or B==null)
finish;
return;
```

then the same in activity B. This works and C and B are finished and A pops up..
HOWEVER in the meantime...

fragments onCreate && onCreateView fire before C onDestroy is invoked. Because I have a lot of fragments in activity C this creates app crashes.

So, my question is. Is there a way to force app restart in this scenario while in activity C onCreate (not null) (or even outside C onCreate; in manifest?) so that fragments onCreate & onCreateView are not invoked?

P.S : I have tried clearTaskonLaunch in manifest but that will force app restarts even when I just pause/resume the screen.

Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar scenario. It seems that sending a `null` value to the base class's `OnCreate` prevents the fragments from reloading. Here is a snippet of my code for a base Activity class (it's in C# Xamarin.Android, but is simple enough to understand):

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (IsInvalidAppState()) {
            GoToLoginActivity();
            base.OnCreate(null);
        } else {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

    private void GoToLoginActivity()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(LoginActivity));
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    private bool IsInvalidAppState()
    {
        // Figure out if everything is initialized correctly
    }
```